# Django Template: using double curly brace in template tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates, templatetags

What I am trying to do is allow different, but very similar views to use the same template. There is a url reference, where the only thing that differs between them is the second half of the reverse call. Using the example below, I get a `NoReverseMatch`, which makes sense if the code below is not accepted.

`{% url outer:{{suffix}} %}`

What is the correct way to achieve this? or do I have sacrifice conciseness, and write out the url?

I am using Django 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'with' to build url and then pass it to url template tag:

```
{% with 'outer:'|add:suffix as link_url %}
    <a href="{% url link_url %}">link</a>
{% endwith %}
```

**UPD: For django 1.4 to make it work, you should add `{% load url from future %}`**, like this:

my_template.html:

```
{% load url from future %}
{% url 'outer:'|add:suffix %}
```

Should print your url correctly. Note, you shouldn't wrap suffix with '', as it's variable.

Comment: How exactly this didn't work? I mean I'm getting the right url using this approach. It looks like details of your question are not enough clear for me(

Comment: Sorry that wasn't very specific. When I run the the snippet as is, I get `NoReverseMatch` highlighting the the link in the `<a>`. When I add quotations around `suffix` as Django says to do for custom template tags, the same thing happens. I appreciate the help, what other knowledge would  be helpful?

Comment: I've updated the answer - it should work for django 1.4. I'm using the 1.10, that's why it wasn't working - `url from future` should do it.

Answer (score -3):

I'll suggest you create [templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/) instead. That way you'll be able to provide the suffix to the templatetag.

**Try wrapping it in quotes like so: `{% url "outer:{{suffix}}" %}`.